# I get the following message when I want to publish what should I do?

Tags: git, git-submodules

I am having problems with publishing my changes made in my portal, the following error appears, can someone help me.

[image: image error]

Comment: You have a *submodule*. Read about submodules before you proceed. Note: there are no *errors* shown here, just the fact that you have a submodule that does not have changes committed to the submodule.

Answer (score 0):

First, make sure the files are properly saved (Ctrl+S).

Your error says that the file was not staged to commit. To fix this issue you need to commit your files.

Command to do it is:

```
git add -A
```

After that your files will be staged and ready for commit:

```
git commit -m "commit message comment goes here"
```

Comment: Hi Dennis, thanks for your responses.

but I have placed the code and the same thing continues to appear. 

[link](https://ibb.co/0jR4YTq)

Excuse me, I'm really new at this.

Comment: It might be that you did not save your files before doing it, are they all properly saved? I made an edit to the answer. If it helps you, please accept (checkmark) and upvote my answer!

Answer (score 0):

seems like you are new to git

Step 1: if you make any changes in your git repository, you have to stage those changes before committing. so here you have modified Portal_Callao file, in order to stage those changes use command:

```
 git add Portal_Callao
```

or you can use

```
git add -A
```

to stage all your changed/modified files

step 2:
now you are ready to commit your modified changes, for committing the changes use the command:

```
git commit -m "Your commit message"
```

Comment: Yes, i'm new t_t

Sorry when you mention typing the git add -A code, should I write it exactly like this or what?

I'm really new to this. sorry

Comment: -A basically means add all modified/newly created/changed files. So in order to stage only one file at a time you use git add (filename) but if you want to add all the changes that happened in repo you use git add -A always